# Oracle convert hhmmss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: oracle

I have some timestamp data in an old Oracle database that needs converting into HH:MM:SS. After trying to use to_char function, the value I give is not readable (E.g. 105001, to_char('105001','HH24:MI:SS)), this SQL will break. I can convert sysdate into the incorrect format but I can't reverse the procedure.

For example:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HHmiss')from table
```

returns '105001'

I need something that will convert the hhmmss format into HH:MM:SS so when I produce a select statement it is in a readable format.

Comment: `105001` is a number, and `'105001'` is a string (so passing that into `to_char()` doesn't really make sense). Neither is a timestamp. What data type are you actually starting from? It isn't clear what you are really trying to do, so sample data and expected results might be helpful. I suspect you're actually just looking at an unhelpful NLS setting but it's really hard to tell...

Comment: you need to convert your number into a date first, e.g. `to_char(to_date(105001, 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your values are a NUMBER in the database which is six-digits long and represents an HHMMSS value you can format it as you want by using SUBSTR:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SOME_TIMESTAMP, 'FM000000'), 1, 2) || ':' ||
       SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SOME_TIMESTAMP, 'FM000000'), 3, 2) || ':' ||
       SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SOME_TIMESTAMP, 'FM000000'), 5, 2)
  FROM cteNumbers
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6aef83848e228170b02b35d37656e8f)

Answer (score 2):

You can first select from **dual** table which is virtual table

**There are 2 different way to have time**

**24 hours : like 5 and 15**

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS')from dual
```

Result

```
14:25:56
```

**12 hours : like 2 AM and 2 PM**

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS AM')from dual
```

Result

```
02:22:35 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have some timestamp data in an old Oracle database that needs converting into `HH:MM:SS`

Just use `HH24` to get a 24-hour clock and add the `:` separators to your format model and then apply that format directly to your `TIMESTAMP` column using the `TO_CHAR` function:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( your_timestamp_column TIMESTAMP );

INSERT INTO table_name ( your_timestamp_column )
  VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2018-09-24 12:34:56' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( your_timestamp_column, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34d5b/1/0)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(YOUR_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN,'HH24:MI:SS') |
|---------------------------------------------|
|                                    12:34:56 |
```

You do not need to output it as a `HHMMSS` string and then try to reformat it to add separators as that is needlessly complicated.